# Solving a time-dependent Schrödinger equation

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, matrix, numerical-integration

I want to solve the time-dependent Schrödinger equation:

$$ i\partial_t \psi(t) = H(t)\psi(t)$$

for matrix, time-dependent $H(t)$ and vector $\psi$.

What is an efficient way of doing this so that it efficiently scales to high-dimensional spaces?

Comment: what are the valuse of b and omega for the second plot? I want to check my code to see is working or not!
Thanks
Jiyan.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Time-dependent case**

in the time-dependent case, $[H(t),H(t')]\neq0$ in  general and we need to time-order, ie, the operator taking a state from $t=0$ to $t=\tau$ is $U(0,\tau)=\mathcal{T}\exp(-i\int_0^\tau dt\, H(t))$ with $\mathcal{T}$ the time-ordering operator. In practice we just split the time interval into lots of small pieces (basically using the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff thing).

So, consider the time-dependent Hamiltonian for a two-level system:

$$
H = 
\left(
    \begin{array}{cc}
        \epsilon_1      && b \cos(\omega t) \\
        b\cos(\omega t) && \epsilon_2       \\
    \end{array}
\right)
$$

i.e. two level coupled by a time-periodic driving (see [here](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.138.B979)). Even this simplest possible periodically-driven system can't be solved analytically in general.

Anyway, here's a function to construct the hamiltonian:

```
ham[e1_, e2_, b_, omega_, 
  t_] := {{e1, b*Cos[omega*t]}, {b*Cos[omega*t], e2}}
```

and here's one to construct the propagator from some initial time to some final time, given a function to construct the Hamiltonian matrix at each point in time (and splitting the interval into $n$ slices--you should try with increasing $n$ until your results stop changing):

```
ClearAll@constructU;
constructU::usage = "constructU[h,tinit,tfinal,n]";
constructU[h_, tinit_, tfinal_, n_] := 
 Module[{dt = N[(tfinal - tinit)/n], 
   curVal = IdentityMatrix[Length@h[0]]}, 
  Do[curVal = MatrixExp[-I*h[t]*dt].curVal, {t, tinit, tfinal - dt, 
    dt}];
  curVal]
```

This constructs the operator $U(0,\tau)=\mathcal{T}\exp(-i\int_0^\tau dt\,H(t))$ as
$$
   U(0,\tau)\approx\prod_{n=0}^{N}\exp\left( -iH(ndt)dt \right)
$$
with $N=\tau/dt-1$ (or its ceiling anyway). This is an approximation to the correct $U$.

And now here is how to look at the time-dependent expectation of $\sigma_z$ for different coupling strengths $b$:

```
ClearAll[cU, psi0];
psi0 = {1., 0};
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[
  Table[
   Chop[#\[Conjugate].PauliMatrix[3].#] &@(constructU[
       ham[-1., 1., b, 1., #] &, 0, upt, 100].psi0),
   {upt, .01, 20, .1}
   ],
  Joined -> True,
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}
  ],
 {b, 0, 2}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, you could calculate the wavefunction at some time `tfinal` given the wavefunction at time `tinit` with this:

```
propPsi[h_, psi0_, tinit_, tfinal_, n_] := 
 Module[{dt = N[(tfinal - tinit)/n],
   psi = psi0},
  Do[
   psi = MatrixExp[-I*h[t]*dt, psi], {t, tinit, tfinal - dt, dt}
   ];
  psi]
```

which uses the form `MatrixExp[-I*h*t,v]`. For large sparse matrices (eg, for `h` a many-body Hamiltonian), this can be much faster at the cost of losing access to $U$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all this. However as you mentioned in your previous comment, my problem is a time-dependent schrodinger equation. In this case, the Hamiltonian doesn't commute in different times, and it can't just be a simple exponential; it should be a path ordered exponential. This is the reason that I can't do this. Such this problems don't have an analytical solution, they ave to be solved numerically!!

Comment: @Zahra For a time-dep H, you can simply construct the propagator from $t=0$ to some time $t=\tau$, say. I can explain how if you want. but let me know if you actually want so I don't waste my time if you insist on doing it with `NDSolve`--but ask yourself which is the most practical way if you have a hilbert space of dimension 20000, for instance (so you'd need to solve 20000 coupled ODEs with your approach)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time that you give to ask my question. I really appreciate that. I'm not insisting to solve my problem with NDSolve. It would be great if I can solve it the way you are explaining. I just thought it is not possible to solve it non-numerically. Can you please tell me how to do that? I appreciate it.

Comment: @Zahra oh I see, no, what I suggest is fully numerical. You're absolutely right that such problems cannot be solved analytically in general. OK let me write it up quickly and you can see if it's useful (I routinely use this on systems with much bigger Hilbert spaces than yours, up to 20-30000)

Comment: here you go (I had actually done this the first time, just posted only the time-independent limit because I did not realize you had a time-dependent hamiltonian). Note that the way I construct the `Manipulate` is not efficient because I recalculate $U$ from scratch all the time, but it's fast enough...

Comment: Thanks 1000 times for your answer. I think it is going to solve my problem. I will continue using this method. However, I have some questions regarding your code: Can you please explain what your are doing in the second part of your code? What is `constructU`? Sorry for taking a lot of your time ...

Comment: @Zahra not a problem, ask away. Basically, it constructs the operator $U(0,\tau)$ mentioned earlier, by explicitly propagating the system over lots of small time intervals, over which the propagator is just the exponential of the instantaneous Hamiltonian times dt; so it just multiplies all these exponentials together (time-slicing).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8020/discussion-between-acl-and-zahra)

Comment: Thanks A LOT for all your help. I am now trying to use it for my own problem. Your explanation helped me a lot. I appreciate that.

Comment: @Zahra any chance of going to the chat room above?

Comment: Sorry I was working on another code and I have just seen your comment. Yes sure, I just don't know how I can find you ...

Comment: @Zahra just click where it says "continue this discussion in chat" in my comment above

Comment: Another common method is splitting operator method which can conserve the norm.

Answer (score 14):

Since there hasn't been any discussion of `NDSOlve` yet, let me point out that for a finite-dimensional Hilbert space where the Schrödinger equation is merely a first-order equation in time, it's easiest to just do this (using the two-dimensional  Hamiltonian `ham` from acl's answer):

```
ham[e1_, e2_, b_, omega_, 
   t_] := {{e1, b*Cos[omega*t]}, {b*Cos[omega*t], e2}};
Manipulate[Module[{ψ, sol, tMax = 20},
  sol = First@NDSolve[{I D[ψ[t], t] == 
       ham[-1, 1, b, 1, t] .ψ[t], ψ[0] == {1,0}}, ψ, {t, 0, tMax}];
  Plot[Chop[#\[Conjugate].PauliMatrix[3].#] &@(ψ /. sol)[t], 
     {t, 0, tMax}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
  ],
 {{b, 1}, 0, 2}
 ]
```

[image: manipulate]

I copied the parameters from acl's answer too, to show the direct comparison in the `Manipulate`. Here the vector $\psi$ is recognized by `NDSolve` as two-dimensional, so the formulation of the problem is quite concise, and we can leave the time step choice up to *Mathematica* instead of choosing a discretization ourselves.

Comment: In fact the original question explicitly mentioned `NDSolve` (I edited it to make it less localized). There's nothing wrong with `NDSolve` for up to a few thousand states, but the approach I gave scales much better (I use it for systems with dimensions in the tens of thousands; `NDSolve` seems to tank much earlier); of course the way I wrote the code it's inefficient.

Comment: as an additional comment, this approach (using `NDSolve` directly) works also for cases where the "Hamiltonian" depends on the wavefunction, so that we have a set of nonlinear coupled ODEs. This kind of problem appears in various mean-field approaches to many-body systems (eg, Gutzwiller-ansatz approach to many-body dynamics of bosons, see eg eq 3 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.0575v2.pdf) ). I've used `NDSolve` for precisely this problem with up to a couple of thousand coupled ODEs; it's really not practical at those sizes, but there's no alternative (in mma) for nonlinear ODEs.

Comment: @acl Thanks for pointing that out (I already upvoted your answer). I think it would have been better to edit the question in such a way as to retain some information on what the OP originally tried already.

Comment: feel free to change it, I would not object (and I imagine neither would Zahra). I thought the question as it was was way too localized (eg, it was asked about a specific Hamiltonian, defined only in hard-to read code--take a look at the original form if you haven't) and wanted to make it as general as possible so it's useful. I think that phrasing it the current way it admits as many approaches as possible.

Comment: @acl I see your point. No worries, it's fine the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Frame it as a set of Linear ODEs and solve it somehow. I usually use Implicit Runge Kutta in the interaction picture.

```
solver[H_, a_] := 
soln = Module[{d, init, eq, vars, solargs, t, t0, tf}, 
d = Dimensions[H][[1]];
t0 = a[[2]];
tf = a[[3]];
t = a[[1]];
u[t_] := Table[Subscript[u, i, j][t], {i, 1, d}, {j, 1, d}];
init = (u[t0] == IdentityMatrix[d]);
eq = (I u'[t] == H.u[t]);
vars = Flatten[Table[Subscript[u, i, j], {i, 1, d}, {j, 1, d}]];
solargs = LogicalExpand[eq && init];
Return[
 NDSolve[solargs, vars, a, 
  Method -> {"FixedStep", 
    Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 10}}, 
  StartingStepSize -> tf/100, MaxSteps -> Infinity]]];

U[t_] := u[t] /. soln[[1]]
```

Alternatively, you could solve for the $\psi(t)$ and obtain U as $|\psi(t)\rangle\langle \psi(0)| $ and use an appropriate normalisation to preserve probability.