# How to solve time dependent Optical Bloch Equations for a three level system?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to solve the optical block equations for three level system which are time dependent, which i generated using the "Atomic Density Matrix" package.

When i use the command to solve this 9 linear coupled differential equations with some initial conditions it is showing me no enough memory is available.

So what should be the system requirements to solve them Analytically ?? i have to increase the RAM or hard disk memory or anything else ?

Similarly i want to work out for five level system where there will be 25 such equations.

here are the equations with initial conditions.

```
variable = {Subscript[ρ, 1, 1][t], Subscript[ρ, 1, 2][t],Subscript[ρ, 1, 3][t], Subscript[ρ, 2, 1][t], Subscript[ρ, 2, 2][t], Subscript[ρ, 2, 3][t],Subscript[ρ, 3, 1][t], Subscript[ρ, 3, 2][t], Subscript[ρ, 3, 3][t]};


init = {Subscript[ρ, 1, 1][0] == 1, Subscript[ρ, 1, 2][0] == 0, Subscript[ρ, 1, 3][0] == 0, Subscript[ρ, 2, 1][0] == 0, Subscript[ρ, 2, 2][0] == 0, Subscript[ρ, 2, 3][0] == 0, Subscript[ρ, 3, 1][0] == 0, Subscript[ρ, 3, 2][0] == 0, Subscript[ρ, 3, 3][0] == 0};



 equations = {Derivative[1][Subscript[ρ, 1, 1]][t] == γ/
 2 - γ Subscript[ρ, 1, 1][t] - 
 I (1/2 ΩRa Subscript[ρ, 1, 3][t] - 
    1/2 ΩRa Subscript[ρ, 3, 1][t]) + 
 1/2 Γ Subscript[ρ, 3, 3][t], 

   Derivative[1][Subscript[ρ, 1, 2]][
     t] == -γ Subscript[ρ, 1, 2][t] - 
     I (Δa Subscript[ρ, 1, 2][
          t] - Δb Subscript[ρ, 1, 2][t] + 
        1/2 ΩRb Subscript[ρ, 1, 3][t] - 
        1/2 ΩRa Subscript[ρ, 3, 2][t]), 
   Derivative[1][Subscript[ρ, 1, 3]][t] == 
    1/2 (-γ Subscript[ρ, 1, 3][
          t] - (γ + Γ) Subscript[ρ, 1, 3][
          t]) - I (1/2 ΩRa Subscript[ρ, 1, 1][t] + 
        1/2 ΩRb Subscript[ρ, 1, 2][
          t] + Δa Subscript[ρ, 1, 3][t] - 
        1/2 ΩRa Subscript[ρ, 3, 3][t]), 
   Derivative[1][Subscript[ρ, 2, 1]][
     t] == -γ Subscript[ρ, 2, 1][t] - 
     I (-Δa Subscript[ρ, 2, 1][
          t] + Δb Subscript[ρ, 2, 1][t] + 
        1/2 ΩRa Subscript[ρ, 2, 3][t] - 
        1/2 ΩRb Subscript[ρ, 3, 1][t]), 
   Derivative[1][Subscript[ρ, 2, 2]][t] == γ/
     2 - γ Subscript[ρ, 2, 2][t] - 
     I (1/2 ΩRb Subscript[ρ, 2, 3][t] - 
        1/2 ΩRb Subscript[ρ, 3, 2][t]) + 
     1/2 Γ Subscript[ρ, 3, 3][t], 
   Derivative[1][Subscript[ρ, 2, 3]][t] == 
    1/2 (-γ Subscript[ρ, 2, 3][
          t] - (γ + Γ) Subscript[ρ, 2, 3][
          t]) - I (1/2 ΩRa Subscript[ρ, 2, 1][t] + 
        1/2 ΩRb Subscript[ρ, 2, 2][
          t] + Δb Subscript[ρ, 2, 3][t] - 
        1/2 ΩRb Subscript[ρ, 3, 3][t]), 
   Derivative[1][Subscript[ρ, 3, 1]][t] == 
    1/2 (-γ Subscript[ρ, 3, 1][
          t] - (γ + Γ) Subscript[ρ, 3, 1][
          t]) - I (-(1/2) ΩRa Subscript[ρ, 1, 1][
          t] - 1/2 ΩRb Subscript[ρ, 2, 1][
          t] - Δa Subscript[ρ, 3, 1][t] + 
        1/2 ΩRa Subscript[ρ, 3, 3][t]), 
   Derivative[1][Subscript[ρ, 3, 2]][t] == 
    1/2 (-γ Subscript[ρ, 3, 2][
          t] - (γ + Γ) Subscript[ρ, 3, 2][
          t]) - I (-(1/2) ΩRa Subscript[ρ, 1, 2][
          t] - 1/2 ΩRb Subscript[ρ, 2, 2][
          t] - Δb Subscript[ρ, 3, 2][t] + 
        1/2 ΩRb Subscript[ρ, 3, 3][t]), 
   Derivative[1][Subscript[ρ, 3, 3]][
     t] == -I (-(1/2) ΩRa Subscript[ρ, 1, 3][t] - 
        1/2 ΩRb Subscript[ρ, 2, 3][t] + 
        1/2 ΩRa Subscript[ρ, 3, 1][t] + 
        1/2 ΩRb Subscript[ρ, 3, 2][
          t]) - (γ + Γ) Subscript[ρ, 3, 3][
       t]};
         TableForm[solution = DSolve[Join[equations, init], variable, t]]
```

If it has to be solved numerically then how to do that ?

can any one help me out with this ?

Comment: Please rewrite your question. Try to avoid Subsript functions and greek letters- > it will be much easier to read your code. Also, if there are 9 coupled differential equations, I would go with NDSolve.

Comment: Well, the ODEs are generated by some kind of matrix calculations, right? I'd rather you showed us the original one. Also, solving DEs in _Mathematica_ is not simply a programming issue, a good understanding for the original problem is often necessary IMO. I think you'd better include some background information about your DEs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

Because of the question's title, I assumed initially that you're interested in the general case of time-dependent driving. This complication is briefly addressed in the first part of my answer.

However, the actual system of differential equations in the question has purely time-independent coefficients and is therefore easier to solve in principle. The only major issue is the appearance of many parameters which *Mathematica* by default assumes to be general complex numbers satisfying no special assumptions. By making the parameters numerical, you get the solutions easily, as shown in the second part below.

**End edit**

Here is a simpler example to show that *Mathematica* can at least get analytical results for the undamped periodically driven two-level system. I compare the result of `DSolve` with the textbook Rabi formula for the occupation probability of the excited state at the end:

```
Clear[e0, v0, ω, t, c1, c2];

$Assumptions = {e0 > 0, v0 > 0, ω > 0, t > 0};

h0 = ( {
    {-e0/2, 0},
    {0, e0/2}
   } );

v = ( {
    {0, v0 E^(I ω t)},
    {v0 E^(-I ω t), 0}
   } );

vi = Simplify[MatrixExp[I h0 t].v.MatrixExp[-I h0 t]];

ψ[t_] = {c1[t], c2[t]} /. 
   Simplify@
    First@DSolve[
      Join[Thread[
        vi.{c1[t], c2[t]} == I {c1'[t], c2'[t]}], {c1[0] == 1, 
        c2[0] == 0}], {c1[t], c2[t]}, t];

FullSimplify[
 ComplexExpand[Last[Conjugate[ψ[t]] ψ[t]]] == 
  v0^2/(v0^2 + (ω - e0)^2/4)
    Sin[Sqrt[v0^2 + (ω - e0)^2/4] t]^2]

(* ==> True *)
```

The last line means that the analytical result derived by `DSolve` agrees with a know textbook formula.

Here I defined the time-dependent potential `v` and then transformed it to the interaction picture `vi`. The coefficients `c1`, `c2` are the interaction-picture amplitudes, and their absolute square yields the occupation probabilities. If I introduce a damping term into this two-level equation, `DSolve` no longer yields a solution.

This means that for a more general problem than what I'm doing here, it's likely that the best bet is a numerical approach as described in [Solving a time-dependent Schroedinger equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21751/245).

**Addressing the equations in the question**

You only need to perform some small additions to your original code to get the numerical result:

```
ΩRa = 1;
ΩRb = 1.1;
Δa = .1;
Δb = -.1;
Γ = .01;
γ = .001;

NDSolve[Join[equations, init], variable, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Here I defined all the variable parameters of the problem by assigning them (completely arbitrary) numbers. This is of course where you have to provide additional information to make the correct choice. Then in `NDSolve` you need to specify a time interval, and you're done.

**Edit: Analytical results with numerical coefficients**

Because there is no driving term, `DSolve` actually **does produce a result** if you just follow the last suggestion and specify all the parameters in terms of numerical values. Here is what that looks like:

```
solution = DSolve[Join[equations, init], variable, t];
Short[solution[[1,1]],10]
```

[image: rho11]

Some of the parameters were specified as machine-precision numbers, so you get corresponding numerical factors in the output as well. One could in principle try with exact numbers as input for `DSOlve`, but that runs much too slowly so I didn't wait for it to complete.

The fact that `DSolve` can solve this system also suggests that one could get it to derive a general result with symbolic parameters, but that requires tweaking the `Assumptions` for those parameters, which is not always successful.

The solution in the present case has the simple form of a matrix exponential, but that exponential is difficult to compute symbolically because of the many parameters in the matrix. However, you can make use of the formal solution to define a straightforward function that will spit out a solution for arbitrary initial conditions as follows:

```
Clear[ΩRa, ΩRb, Δa, Δb, Γ, γ];

j = D[equations[[All, 2]], {variable}];

initVec = init[[All, 2]]

(* ==> {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)

liouville[ΩRa_, ΩRb_, Δa_, Δb_, Γ_, γ_] := MatrixExp[t j];

ΩRa = 1;
ΩRb = 1.1;
Δa = .1;
Δb = -.1;
Γ = .01;
γ = .001;

sol = 
  liouville[ΩRa, ΩRb, Δa, Δb, Γ, γ].initVec;

Plot[Evaluate[Abs@sol], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: plots]

Here I first defined the matrix of coefficients `j` for your linear, constant-coefficient differential equation in `9` variables, by taking derivatives with respect to `variable`. Then I define a function `liouville` that performs the matrix exponential if it is provided with the necessary parameters. Here you will have to insert the *numerical* parameters to get an actual result. Then the time evolution is simply obtained by multiplying the vector of initial conditions `initVec` with this matrix. The plot shows what the result looks like for the same choice of parameters I used above.

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate explanation.Yes "DSolve" working well for numerical coefficients of the DE's. I tried it for five level of Rb87 atom also i.e., 25 linear coupled ODE's and it solved in 2 minutes. Finally i want to solve a 25 level of Cs133 atom which is my ultimate goal of this exercise. When i did that even after running for 2 days continuously it is showing me "Running...". So, what i can do now ? weather i have to increase the RAM size(4GB presently) or just keep it running ? how to calculate the time it could take for solving linear coupled differential equations ?

Comment: Can't say anything without seeing the equations, but first order of business has to be to eliminate all unnecessary parameters by suitable rescaling. But purely symbolic solutions are unlikely to be viable for high dimensions. I don't understand whether you're using numerical coefficients or not.