# Time evolution of a wave packet from the time-independent Schroedinger equation

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration

Starting off with the time-independent Schroedinger equation (TISE)

$\quad \quad 
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \psi + V(r, \theta) \psi = E\, \psi,$

I would like to study the time evolution of an initial wave packet $\psi(0)$ dropped in the potential $V$. In particular, I want to evaluate $\langle \theta \rangle$ as a function of the time $t$.

The TISE for the potential $V$ does not have any exact solution in terms of any known functions. The wave packet $\psi (0)$ is expressed as a linear combination of a certain class of functions (infinite in number), which form a basis, but are NOT eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.

I noticed [a similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21751/solving-a-time-dependent-schroedinger-equation/21781#21781) which uses the time-ordering operator. In that context, my questions were as follows:

- Given a Hamiltonian in differential form (with a particularly nasty $\nabla^2$ in polar coordinates), how does one convert it to its matrix form using *Mathematica*, considering that the basis used to express $\psi(0)$ has infinitely many functions?
- Is there some way to implement $\exp \big(\partial/ \partial \theta \big)$ directly as a function operating on an argument in *Mathematica*? As suggested by my attempts, *Mathematica* does not seem to recognise the dangling derivative in the exponential.

Having an answer to Part 1 of my question would enable me to generalise [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21781) to the problem at hand. However, I would certainly welcome any efficient approach to the direct computation of $\langle \theta \rangle (t)$ that you may suggest.

---

#### Edit

Just to prevent confusion about the second part of the question, by $\exp \big(\partial/ \partial \theta \big)$, I mean

$\quad \quad 
\exp \big(\partial/ \partial \theta \big) =  1 + \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} + \frac{1}{2!}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} + \ldots$

So $\exp \big(\partial/ \partial x \big) (x^2) = 1 + 2x + x^2 \ne \exp(2x)$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: This is a time-independent problem, and your first link is to a time-dependent solution. They are very different problems. Also the link doesn't use the time-ordering operator (although it's mentioned), it just discretizes time. If you want to a time-dependent 2D problem, see [this link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27842/245).

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\exp(\partial_x)\left\{x^2\right\} = 1 + 2x + x^2$?

Comment: @Jens, Starting with a solution of the time-independent problem, one can propagate it in time using $\exp (- \mathrm{i} H t / \hbar)$ to obtain $\psi(t)$, so the problems are related. If you want, equivalently, you can find $\psi (t)$ directly from the time-dependent equation and compute $\langle \theta \rangle$. **Note:** I'm not trying to solve the TISE, I'm just trying to evolve a given wave packet which is NOT necessarily a solution of the TISE (read as eigenstate of $H$).

Comment: So then you want something like this, right? [Complex valued 2+1D PDE Schroedinger equation, numerical method for `NDSolve`?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27842/245)

Comment: For the second part of the question, I assume you want a more general operator $\exp(\alpha \partial/\partial \theta)$, because without the additional parameter $a$ the expression would be pretty useless. One could see that part as a duplicate of [Exponential of a Differential Operator](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51514/245). But if you could be more specific about the actual problem and your solution attempts, there may be a way to give a more specific answer, too.

Comment: If the link in my previous comment answers your question, then I think the question can be closed. The second part is Taylor's formula: $\exp(a \partial/\partial x) f(x) = f(x+a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Try this exponential derivative operator:

```
expD[f_, x_] := 
 Module[{x0},
  Sum[SeriesCoefficient[f, {x, x0, i}], {i, 0, \[Infinity]}] /. {x0 -> x}
 ]
```

Examples:

```
expD[x^2, x]
(* (1 + x)^2 *)

expD[Sin[x], x]
(* Sin[1 + x] *)

expD[Exp[x], x]
(* Exp[1 + x] *)
```

Comment: (+1), but I think this part is a duplicate of [Exponential of a Differential Operator](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51514/245)

Comment: @Jens Should I move this answer there?

Comment: It does seem like your answer belongs to that linked question, since this one mentions the exponential only as a part of the problem... but actually, the answer for the special case here is trivial: your operator, applied to *any* function $f(x)$, is simply equivalent to $f(x+1)$ by the Taylor formula.